# List styles not displaying

Tags: css

On this page: http://catonthecouchproductions.com/fish/boat-captain.html I have a list on the bottom right box in yellow, but it is not displaying as a list-style-type:circle, but i have it set in my CSS.

I am not sure why it is acting this way. Any ideas?

I have FireBug installed and it doesn't seem like anything is conflicting with it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to add a `left-margin` to `li` to get them to show up.

```
ul li { margin-left: 10px; }
```

should do it

Answer (score 1):

You haven't left any space for the circle to display - try `margin:1px 10px;` on the ul li instead

Answer (score 0):

`list-style-type:circle;` should be defined for the ul and not the li.

Answer (score 0):

Add a padding to the `ul` element that has been reset by `reset.css`.

Answer (score 0):

Another detail, that I saw: your `<ul>` element has `list-style-type:disc;` and the `<li>` elements `list-style-type:circle;`. This property should only be declared for the `<ul>` element.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, when floating li.
As soon as I removed float from li element, the circles in ul showed up in IE7.